# Why doesn't this symbolic link work for access_log

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I've created a link like this:

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log -> /var/www/html/mylog.txt
```

with the command:

```
ln -s /var/log/httpd/access_log /var/www/html/mylog.txt
```

I have made sure that the following files/directories can be read (0666):

```
/var/
/var/log/
/var/log/httpd/
/var/log/httpd/access_log
/var/www
/var/www/html
/var/www/html/mylog.txt
```

But even so, when I try to access `mylog.txt` I get a 403:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /mylog.txt on this server.

I've tried other methods like:

```
readfile("/var/log/httpd/access_log");
echo file_get_contents("/var/log/httpd/access_log");
```

However, within PHP, they both return false.

I'm sure I got all the permissions right though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `www-data` is a user, same as anyone who isn't root. As you probably know, only root can read the httpd access logs, meaning that `www-data` will get access denied. You could either use a cronjob to copy the log to `/var/www/html` or (**not recommended**) run httpd as root.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable running httpd as root, so I guess the next best option would be to chown the logs to www-data. Still not the best option in my opinion but it'll have to do.

Comment: @DaveChen as I said, the best option is to have a cronjob periodically copy the logs to `/var/www/html`

Comment: @DaveChen **NEVER** `chown` logs to `www-data` as that poses a security risk, as `www-data` should never be able to open those protected logs

Comment: I think running httpd as root is more of a security risk. Since, any PHP scripts (if exploited), could `rm -rf /` where as chown to some silly logs that are authentication only under PHP (readfile/file_get_contents).

Comment: If the logs are readonly, how is this different from apache accessing them, versus a cronjob copying them and then apache reading them? Aside from being more synchronized, and more efficient, I can't see a difference.

Comment: @DaveChen it's different, because you're copying the logs to somewhere under apaches control, whereas by chowning the logs, you're giving apache access to a restricted part of the OS

Comment: Sorry I'm still not understanding. I know apache is getting access to /var/logs/httpd/*, but it's readonly and the only files are the access and error logs, just what I need to read in realtime. I don't suppose there's any security risks involved, is there?

Comment: @DaveChen there aren't but it's best practice to copy the logs somewhere that apache **can** read, then access it.

Comment: I guess the only case would be if an extension of apache decided to log in the same folder, and a php script could be exploited into reading that log. Thanks for this answer.